# How to apply Undo and Redo operation to EditText on Button click in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, undo-redo

I am trying to apply Undo and Redo operation while writing or applying effect to my EditText. For that i have downloaded class from this [Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458#c123) and then i have used it like this in my app.

**For Undo**

```
TextViewUndoRedo mTextViewUndoRedo = new TextViewUndoRedo(edtNoteDescription);
mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
```

**For Redo**

```
TextViewUndoRedo mTextViewUndoRedo = new TextViewUndoRedo(edtNoteDescription);
mTextViewUndoRedo.redo();
```

But i don't know why this code does not work, I have put the log and check whether the function Undo is called or not and unfortunately i saw that it is calling this function but it goes inside below method.

```
if (edit == null) {
    return;
}
```

I have also tried with some other solution with no luck, So if anyone who has implemented the same with this method or with any other method then please do suggest some code or way to implement this functionality.

**Edit**

```
btnUndo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 TextViewUndoRedo mTextViewUndoRedo = new TextViewUndoRedo(edtNoteDescription);
                 mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You could implement your own `UNDO/REDO` using a `Queue` or a `Stack`...

Comment: `getPrevious()` method returns null because `mmPosition` inside the `EditHistory` is 0. This means the history is empty. Could it be that you are calling undo on an empty edit text?

Comment: @nem, First of all thank you for the reply, No i am not applying undo on empty edittext. and other thing is that after performing operation why EditHistory is 0. i don't get that ?

Comment: `mmPosition` inside `EditHistory` is 0, not `EditHistory` itself. The `Undo()` method calls `EditItem edit = mEditHistory.getPrevious();` and `edit` is `null` as you've said. That means `getPrevious()` returns `null`. Inside `getPrevious`, the statement `if (mmPosition == 0) { return null; }` is executed so `mmPosition` has to be 0. This is true when the `EditHistory.mmHistory` is empty so that is why i assumed you are applying this on an empty `EditText`. Can you post a bigger chunk of your code showing exactly how you are calling these methods and in what order?

Comment: @nem, I just used above code inside button's clicke event nothing else, and the class itself you can download from the link which i have given. Then also for your understanding i have pasted my code how exactly i have used it in my class.

Comment: Here is the link of the class if you have trouble finding it: https://github.com/jtbuaa/iReaderHome/blob/master/app/src/main/java/fi/iki/asb/android/logo/TextViewUndoRedo.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the problem be that you are creating the `TextViewUndoRedo` object each time the button is clicked?

That is why `EditHistory` is empty cause it's getting recreated each time. 
Wouldn't this work?

```
TextViewUndoRedo mTextViewUndoRedo = new TextViewUndoRedo(edtNoteDescription);

btnUndo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
    }
});
```

Like I said in the comments, The `Undo()` method calls `mEditHistory.getPrevious()` but `getPrevious()` returns `null` because inside of it, it executes:

```
if (mmPosition == 0) { 
    return null; 
}
```

When `TextViewUndoRedo` is created, a new `EditHistory` is created and inside of it `mmPosition` is initialized to 0.
Since you are re-creating the object each time, `mmPosition` is always 0 and you get `null` back.

Comment: Is there any to use undo/redo in Jetpack Compose for a TextField? Thanks