# Undo textView on a button click

Tags: java, android

I have a text view that display text every time a button is clicked.
Ex:on clicking Button A and Button B the text view will display

A,B

I want to have a undo button so that on clicking it the text last displayed gets deleted
In this case B
so the text view should only be displaying A

Any suggestion as to how I can implement it??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808701/how-to-apply-undo-and-redo-operation-to-edittext-on-button-click-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use char array to store the entered characters , and by pressing undo button delete the last char in the array and fetch the last char and put it into textView.

suppose char array is containing A-> B -> C -> D,
now if you press undo then remove D from array and fetch C.
hope this helps.

Comment: OK I'll be able to remove D from the array but what about the textview.

Comment: onClick on undo button remove D and set text in text view like textView.setText(""); , this will remove the entered text and put the last char from array to textView

Comment: And also do check if textView.getText().toString.isEmpty , if true means empty don't save the values in array

Comment: OK I'll be able to remove D from the array but what about the textview.when I press A the first time o/p will be A...later on it will be A,B,C.After cliclking D i have to do textview.settext("" +textview.gettext() +"D ") or as you say   textview.settext("" +textview.gettext() +"" array[i]) where i=3;  Now what to do next for removing it from textview

Comment: just do onClick of undo button                                                                
 String temp = textView.getText().toString().trim();
 textView.setText(temp.substring(0,temp.length()-2));

Comment: this will remove last two char from textView every time you press undo button. and before setting text on undo check if(! temp.toString().isEmpty) otherwise you'll get NPE.

Comment: Thanks... Is there a way I can keep track which button was last clicked by storing maybe their id's in a stack or something

Comment: yes you can store the last clicked button in global int variable and whenever you press any button just get the id of it by button.getId() and put this id in that global variable. Now this varible will be containing the latest pressed button's Id.

Comment: so an int array would be able to hold the button objects??

Comment: no , not button object. it will hold the id of button.

Comment: Welcome, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Simply store text on textview onClick of button A and B before setting text to Textview. On Undo set stored text to Textview.

Answer (score 0):

*Let's say button A prints "Romeo" and button B prints " and Juliet".. and the user clicks them both (in sequence), "Romeo and Juliet" is displayed on the TextView. Clicking the undo button makes "Romeo" (only) appear in your TextView.*

Is this what you mean?

If yes, you can use this approach:

- Start by creating an arraylist of all the words that have been inputted in the textView. In this case, the arraylist has two elements: "Romeo" and " and Juliet". You can keep adding to the arrraylist as more words are being added. (I'm suggesting arraylist because it is resizable).
- When the user presses the undo button, get the last string in the arraylist (for example: `list.get(list.size() - 1)`).. Get the length of this string and store it in a variable (let's call this variable reduction).
- Now get the text in your TextView (the one that's supposed to display the sequence of words).. Turn it to a charArray and just use a for loop to  delete the last 'reduction' characters from the back (reverse).

I hope this helps!

Merry coding!